# Listing posts from database with logic and html separation

Tags: php

I would like to know if there's a way to totally separate logic and HTML (without OOP or template engines for practice and learning purpose) in case of listing posts from database, currently, the code looks like that:

```
<!--TEMPLATE:-->
<?php require_once(HEAD); ?>
  <body>  
    <?php require_once(HEADER); ?>
    <?php require_once(BANNER); ?>
    <!-- Main Content (S) -->
      <main class="container">
      
      <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
      
      $postImg = $row["post_img"];
      $postAuthor = $row["post_author"];
      $postTitle = $row["post_title"];

      <div class="col">
        <div class="card shadow-sm">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="<?= $postImg ?>" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">
              <small class="text-muted"><a class="fw-bold" href=""><?= $postAuthor ?></a></small>
            </p>
            <h5 class="card-title mb-3"><?= $postTitle ?></h5>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <?php endwhile; ?>

      </main>
     <!-- Main Content (E) -->
    <?php require_once(FOOTER); ?>
    <?php require_once(JS_FILES); ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Variables: `$postImg`, `$postAuthor`, `$postTitle` are set with the data from the database.
Currently, the logic of listing posts happens in the same place as the **HTML** post template, I have an idea where I move this post **HTML** to a different template file and I use it in `listPosts()` function by including it on every iteration of the loop.

**Main question: is there a way to leave this post HTML code in the current file and somehow loop it with all the result set rows?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current approach is the good practice because that's how normally people uses PHP with HTML.

You have four options:

- Either follow MVC architecture pattern
- Use template engine
- Keep your HTML only in separate `php` file and include in the logic file.
- Your `php` file with logic but the response is provided to the AJAX call from
  client side that will do the rendering part based on data ( Eg: JSON ).

Example for third option:

your database query script file: `post.php`

```php
<!--TEMPLATE:-->
<?php require_once(HEAD); ?>
  <body>  
    <?php require_once(HEADER); ?>
    <?php require_once(BANNER); ?>
    <!-- Main Content (S) -->
      <main class="container">
      
      <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
      
      $postImg = $row["post_img"];
      $postAuthor = $row["post_author"];
      $postTitle = $row["post_title"];

      // include template
      include 'postView.php';
    
      <?php endwhile; ?>

      </main>
     <!-- Main Content (E) -->
    <?php require_once(FOOTER); ?>
    <?php require_once(JS_FILES); ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Your html file: `postView.php`

```php
<div class="col">
 <div class="card shadow-sm">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="<?= $postImg ?>" alt="Card image cap">
   <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">
     <small class="text-muted"><a class="fw-bold" href=""><?= $postAuthor ?></a></small>
    </p>
    <h5 class="card-title mb-3"><?= $postTitle ?></h5>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just create a `signlePost.php` file and put your html code in it like:

```
<div class="col">
        <div class="card shadow-sm">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="<?= $postImg ?>" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">
              <small class="text-muted"><a class="fw-bold" href=""><?= $postAuthor ?></a></small>
            </p>
            <h5 class="card-title mb-3"><?= $postTitle ?></h5>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

then in your logic file use include or require like that:

```
<!--TEMPLATE:-->
<?php require_once(HEAD); ?>
  <body>  
    <?php require_once(HEADER); ?>
    <?php require_once(BANNER); ?>
    <!-- Main Content (S) -->
      <main class="container">
      
      <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
      
      $postImg = $row["post_img"];
      $postAuthor = $row["post_author"];
      $postTitle = $row["post_title"];

      include 'singlePost.php';

      <?php endwhile; ?>

      </main>
     <!-- Main Content (E) -->
    <?php require_once(FOOTER); ?>
    <?php require_once(JS_FILES); ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

but would be better if you use OOP to structurate your code for better